# How do we know the number of electrons present in atom, if we have not seen the electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

If we cannot see electrons then how do we know how many electrons are present in a given atom, for example, how do we know that oxygen has 8 electrons, Nitrogen - 7 electrons, etc?
What i know is that electrons are not possible to be observed, we have seen nucleus of an atom then how come we say that any given atom has this many electrons?

Comment: how about doing some reading ? http://padakshep.org/otp/subjects/chemistry/physical-chemistry/discovery-of-electrons-protons-and-neutrons/

Comment: Remember that visually "seeing" things is only one way of detecting that something exists. There are other ways as well.

Answer (score 3):

Since about 1913 it was established by the experimental work of Moseley on x-ray emission of atoms (and comparison with the Bohr atomic model) that the atomic number used in the periodic table of elements corresponds to the number of positive elementary charges (proton number) of the atomic nucleus. See Moseleys law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moseley%27s_law . It was known that the positive nucleus was surrounded by negatively charged electrons (each with an elementary charge) and that each atom in its normal state was electrically neutral. Thus it was established experimentally that the number of electrons surrounding the nucleus of the atoms has to be equal to the atomic number which is the proton number in the nucleus.

Comment: *"the number of electrons in the outer shell of the atoms is equal the atomic proton number which is the proton number in the nucleus."* As 'outer shell' is often taken to mean the valence shell, a common reading of this sentence would be incorrect. Perhaps something like "the total number of electrons of an atom is equal to ..." would be better.

Comment: @ dmckee Thank you, the term "outer shell" might be confusing. I used it because at the time of the development of the atomic model it was also conjectured that electrons could reside in the nucleus. Is there no expression in English for the totality of electrons in the atom like the German word "Elektronenhülle", which seems to be translated by "atomic electron shell"?

Comment: I don't know of a technical term that is well understood to have that meaning. "Electron cloud" appears from time to time, but mostly in pop-sci sources. Best I've got.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot "see" electrons with our eyes. But there are lots of experiments in which the presence of electrons can be detected and their behavior can be observed. That information can be transformed to create images (for example STM is sensitive to the local density of electrons so can be used for imaging.) The simplest way to know the number of electrons in an atom is based on studying the charge properties.